# Is it Possible to Install Apache Servicemix in CentOS

Tags: installation, centos, apache-servicemix

Is it Possible to Install Apache Servicemix in CentOS? If Yes what are the requirements?

Answer (score 2):

It's a Java application, so the requirements are a JDK.

Comment: I accepted the answer but i will try myself and confirm it

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, however we required jre/jdk for the installation. You can follow this [document](https://servicemix.apache.org/docs/6.x/quickstart/installation.html).
For better understanding go for  [this](https://linoxide.com/tools/install-apache-servicemix-centos-7/).

Comment: Can you add context for your links?